# Sorting : is it browser specific

Tags: javascript, sorting, browser

When I did sort by title for a set of array values, it gives me 3 different results in Safari,Chrome and Firefox. Why the behaviour is so? I used sproutcore framework. I have used

```
Array.sort(function(a,b){return function2(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4)})
```

`function2` compares my `keyValue`. `function2` in turn calls another compare function to compare the values of the record. This function returns `1`, `-1` or `0` based on

```
record1.localeComapre(record2)
```

Comment: You will have to include your actual comparison function and a sample set of data that illustrates the problem (ideally in a working jsFiddle) for us to be able to offer anything specific.

Comment: thanks. i`l get the screenshot from the browser

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that you're getting different results?

The experience of other folks suggests that the behavior of localeCompare deviates between the browsers.  See http://blog.schmichael.com/2008/07/14/javascript-collation-fail/ for example, as well as http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459

Without seeing in more detail how your comparator works, I can't suggest more at this time.  You could write a quick-and-dirty check afterwards and confirm that the lists are truly sorted; if the results come out positive, then the differences can be attributed to the quirks of localeCompare or the stability of the sorting routine.